# Can not change float variable value

Tags: android, canvas

I use mPosX and mPosY to draw a bitmap at a specific position. I change mPosX and mPosY in a method to change the position of the bitmap. However, mPosX and mPosY are always 0 when I use them in onDraw method. Below is the code snippet:

```
public class CustomZoomableImageView extends 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
......
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, backgroundPaint);
        canvas.save();
        //anvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setTranslate(mPosX,mPosY);
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotPointX,
                pivotPointY);
        // canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDraw, matrix,
                null);
        // this.getDrawable().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
}

    public void syncDragAndZoom(Vector<ParamsZoomable> params){
    ParamsZoomable paramsZoomable = params.get(0);
    mPosX = paramsZoomable.getmPosX();
    mPosY = paramsZoomable.getmPosY();
    mX=paramsZoomable.getmPosX();
    mY=paramsZoomable.getmPosY();
    mScaleFactor = paramsZoomable.getmScaleFactor();
    pivotPointX = paramsZoomable.getPivotPointX();
    pivotPointY = paramsZoomable.getPivotPointY();
    invalidate();
}
......
}

....
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void zoomableReceived(ZoomableCommand command) {
    Vector<ParamsZoomable> params = command.getParams();
    mPresenter.draweeView.syncDragAndZoom(params);
}
```

I call `syncDragAndZoom` to assign a new value to `mPosX` and `mPosY`. But `mPosX` and `mPosY` are always 0. (`syncDragAndZoom` is called by event bus).

Is this a multi-thread issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide us with the definition of `ParamsZoomable` and the code that sets it up.

Comment: Its not related much to my issue. I only get a float value from it.